# JNA native function call and a Structure with a Double**-Pointer/Array Memory-Allocation

Tags: java, c++, native, jna

I'm using a native c++ dll out of an Java application with the JNA framework. I have a problem with a function invocation. Perhaps I'm not allocating the memory properly? I have no opinion, what to try next. I'm not getting any more information helping me out of the documentation and forum threads. I hope you can give me a hint, would be nice.

I want to call a native function (in example `FooInterface`). This function takes a structure `TNativeFoo` as input and output parameter. The structure `TNativeFoo` contains a `Double**`/`Double[][]` data. This field could be seen as a multidimensional array, but the first dimension has only the lenght 1. So its more a pointer pointing to a double array with the size `Items`.

There is also a `StringArray` in the structure (`char**`/`String[]`) with the length `StringsCount`, this is irrellevant, because it isn't used. I mention it because I'm not sure if the error has something to do with this. Below is the definition made for the native dll and the structure.

```
 public interface Foodll extends StdCallLibrary {

    Foodll INSTANCE = (Foodll) Native.loadLibrary("foodll.dll", Foodll.class);

    public static class TNativeFoo extends com.sun.jna.Structure {

    public TNativeFoo (){
            super();
            setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
        }
        public TNativeFoo(com.sun.jna.Pointer pointer,int offset) {
            super();
            setAlignType(ALIGN_NONE);
            useMemory(pointer,offset);
            read();
        }
        public TNativeFoo(TNativeFoo struct) {
        this(struct.getPointer(),0);
    }

        public static class ByReference extends TNativeFoo implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByReference {
            ByReference() {}
            ByReference(TNativeFoo struct){super(struct.getPointer(),0);}
        }
        public static class ByValue extends TNativeFoo implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByValue {
            ByValue() {}
            ByValue(TNativeFoo struct){super(struct.getPointer(),0);}
        }

        public PointerByReference Data;
        public NativeLong Items;
        public PointerByReference IrrelevantStringArray;
        public NativeLong StringsCounts = new NativeLong(0);
    }

    NativeLong FooInterface(TNativeFoo input, TNativeFoo output);
}
```

For the call to the function I try to allocate the memory on the native heap and write the data to it. After writing the data to the native heap like in the example I could read it like I did in the example with alternative 2 (I tried this without invoking the native function, and directly from the `inputFoo`). Invoking the native function like in the example below throws me a fatal exception.

Invocation:

```
public class FooInvocationClass
{
    public static FooInvocationMethod(double[] fooData)
    {

                Foodll foodllJnaLib = Foodll.INSTANCE;

                Foodll.TNativeFoo outputFoo = new Foodll.TNativeFoo();
                Foodll.TNativeFoo inputFoo = new Foodll.TNativeFoo();

        //Writing input data to the native heap
                Memory dataPointer = new Memory (fooData.length * Double.SIZE);
                dataPointer.write(0, fooData, 0, fooData.length);

                inputFoo.Data = new PointerByReference();
                inputFoo.Data.setValue(dataPointer);

                outputProfile.Data = new PointerByReference();
                inputFoo.Items = outputFoo.Items = new NativeLong(fooData.length);

        //Setting some irrelevant StringArray Parameters
                inputFoo.IrrelevantStringArray = outputFoo.IrrelevantStringArray = new PointerByReference();
                inputFoo.StringsCounts = outputFoo.StringsCounts = new NativeLong(0);


        //Invocation
        foodllJnaLib.FooInterface(inputFoo, outputFoo);

        //Reading Output
                Pointer outputFooDataPointer = outputFoo.Data.getValue();

        //Reading Output alternative  1
                Double[] outDataAlt1 = outputFooDataPointer.getDoubleArray(0, outputFoo.items);

        //Reading Output alternative  2
                Double[] outDataAlt2 = new Double[outputFoo.items];
                for (int x = 0; x < outputFoo.items; x += 1)
                {
                    outDataAlt2[x] = outputFooDataPointer.getDouble(x * 8);
                }
        }
}
```

Exception:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0x0), pid=5904, tid=220
#
# JRE version: 7.0_04-b22
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xb9bc]  RaiseException+0x58
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\Programme\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\bin\hs_err_pid5904.log
#
```

I also could imagine that there is a problem with the 32bit JVM and native code running on a 64bit system. I had installed a 32bit JVM on my 64-bit system as I was struckeling with a problem JNA "didn't find the native dlls".

## Edit:

I found a mistake I made, I looked in the wrong Structure definition, which looks the same, but isn't. So I have to change my question.

But also I made my question was wrong, I tried the suggestions you all made. They helped me understand the topic, and I tried them after I found out about the right structure definition. Thank you for them.

But the Exception stays the same. Perhaps I have more than one error in the code. So here my question again, hopefully now correct and with more Information than before. Had to Foo a few things (in respect to the company), but the semantic stays the same.

I do not really have the h-files or the source code. I came into the Project late and I'm only working on it parttime. Someone else was programming the native calls in C++/CLI  and it worked. So I have attached the code below. Below the c++/CLI codes is the changed Java-Code.

### c++/CLI:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *TFooInterface) (
   LONGLONG *APrgId,
   void *input,
   void *output,
   double value,
   HANDLE AAppHandle,
   HANDLE AProgessBar,
   char *AText, 
   char **ReturnText
   );

//-APrgID is a ID, which tells the Method, what type of processing it should do.
//-The void Pointers both take a TNativeFOO Structure. One is for the input, the other one is for the output.
//-The double-value is a Parameter for the algorithm.
//-The Handle Parameters are for a programm, the dll was created for. They give status about the processing or something like that. We now use the dll in an other context, so they aren't needed anymore.
//-char *AText amd. char **ReturnText are, also not needed anymore. They are for exception handling as far as I know. We handle the Exception in the new Context more general.

typedef struct {
   double         *Data;
   long           Items;
   unsigned char  *String;
   long           StringCounts;
   double         Value1, Value2;
   char           *FileName;
   char           *DataObject;
   char           *Comment;
   bool           Valid;
} TNativeFoo;

//-*Data is a double Array holding the data to process in TFooInterface
//-Items is the lenght of Data
//-*String and StringCounts are not needed anymore, because the dll is used in another way. I can't tell what it is for.
//-Value1, Value2 are Parameters used in the algorithm
//-FileName is for storing the result. Isn't used.
//-DataObject, Comment is also never used. I can't tell what it is for.
//-Valid is a success-flag of the algorithm.

void FooClass::FooIt(double[] FooData, HMODULE hFooLib)
{

    TNativeFoo Input, Output; //Declaration of the Structures   
    LONGLONG PrgID;
    LONGLONG ID;
    double value;

    double[] OutputData = new double[FooData.length];
    ID =-35547318716283305;

    //setting up the Structures 

    memset(&Input, 0, sizeof(TNativeFoo));
    memset(&Output, 0, sizeof(TNativeFoo));

    Output.Data = new double[FooData.length];
    Input.Data =  &(FooData[0]);
    Input.Items = Output.Items = FooData.length;
    Input.Value1 = Output.Value1 = 1.3;
    Input.Value2 = Output.Value2 = 2.3;
    Input.Valid = Output.Valid = true;

    FooInterface = (TFooInterface) GetProcAddress(hFooLib, "FooInterface");
    FooInterface(&ID, &Input, &Output, value, 0, 0, "", NULL);

    for (long i=0; i<Output.Items; i++)
    {
        OutputData[i]= Output.Data[i];
    }

    ...

}
```

### The Java Definitions:

```
public interface Foodll extends StdCallLibrary {

    Foodll INSTANCE = (Foodll) Native.loadLibrary("foodll.dll", Foodll.class);

    //Structure
    public static class TNativeFoo extends com.sun.jna.Structure {

        public TNativeFoo(){
            setAlignType(Structure.ALIGN_NONE);
        }
        public TNativeFoo(com.sun.jna.Pointer pointer, int offset) {
            super(pointer.share(offset));
            setAlignType(Structure.ALIGN_NONE); //Tested all align-types. I was told this is the one used by the dlls
            read();
        }
        public TNativeFoo(TNativeProfile struct) {
            super(struct.getPointer());
            setAlignType(Structure.ALIGN_NONE); //Tested all align-types. I was told this is the one used by the dlls
            read();
        }
        public static class ByReference extends TNativeFoo implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByReference {
            ByReference() {}
            ByReferenceTNativeFoo struct){super(struct.getPointer(),0);}
        }
       public static class ByValue extends TNativeFoo implements com.sun.jna.Structure.ByValue {
            ByValue() {}
            ByValueTNativeFoo struct){super(struct.getPointer(),0);}
        }
        public Pointer Data;
        public double[] getData() {
            if (this.Data == null) return null;
            return this.Data.getDoubleArray(0, Items.intValue());
        }
        public void setData(double[] data) {
            if (this.Data == null) {
                this.Data = new Memory(data.length * 8);
            }
            this.Data.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
        }
        public NativeLong Items;
        public String String;
        public NativeLong StringCounts = new NativeLong(0);
        public double Value1;
        public double Value2;
        public String FileName;
        public String DataObject;
        public String Comment;
        public boolean Valid;
    }

    NativeLong FooInterface(DoubleByReference prgid, TNativeFoo input, TNativeFoo output, double value, Pointer aAppHandle, Pointer aProgessBar, String AText, String[] ReturnText);
}
```

### Java-Invocation:

```
public class FooInvocationClass
{
        public static FooInvocationMethod(double[] fooData, ID)
        {
                Foodll foodllJnaLib = Foodll.INSTANCE;

                Foodll.TNativeFoo outputFoo = new Foodll.TNativeFoo();
                Foodll.TNativeFoo inputFoo = new Foodll.TNativeFoo();

                inputFoo.setData(fooData);
                outputFoo.setData(new double[fooData.length]);
                inputFoo.Items = outputFoo.Items = new NativeLong(fooData.length);

                inputFoo.String = outputFoo.String = "";
                inputFoo.StringCounts = outputFoo.StringCounts = new NativeLong(0);
                inputFoo.Value1 = outputFoo.Value1 = 0.1;
                inputFoo.Value2 = outputFoo.Value2 = 0.3;

                Double ID =-35547318716283305;
                double value = 0.025;
                impDriveFiltJnaLib.ProfileFilterInterface(new DoubleByReference(ID), input, output, value, null, null, null, null);

                Double[] outDataAlt1 = outputFoo.getDate();
        }
}
```

### Edit 2

Exception has changed after I resolved a Problem with a file error in the dll. The dll had to be copied again. That resolved a problem the dll couldn't be loaded.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x027047b8, pid=800, tid=7584
#
# JRE version: 7.0_04-b22
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [FooDll.dll+0x47b8]  FooInterface+0x2288
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\Programme\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\bin\hs_err_pid800.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Include corresponding native declarations that you're trying to map.

Comment: I found a mistake I made, I looked in the wrong Structure "Information/Documentation", which looks the same. The data field isn't really a Double**-Pointer it is only a Double*-Pointer. So the Question will change dramaticly. Should I Edit and change the whole text, and add the things I let out. Or should I write a new question and Reference the Questions.

Comment: Add a new section under an "EDIT" header, and add a note about the edit to the very top of the question.

Comment: Any unused pointer fields should be Pointer, rather than String.  If you're not certain the underlying data is an initialized C string (or NULL), you're better off not having JNA try to parse it as a String, which will likely result in a crash if it's not a C string.

Comment: Unless you tell it otherwise, JNA will treat Java `boolean` as a native `int`.  Make sure `sizeof(bool)` matches the size of the Java type you use (might be `byte`).  You can also configure JNA to automatically convert between the native `bool` type and boolean by supplying a type mapper (see the usage of `W32APITypeMapper` within JNA which ensures w32 BOOL (an int natively) gets translated into Java boolean and vice versa.

Comment: When you're finished making your structure changes, ensure that `TNativeFoo.size()` matches `sizeof(TNativeFoo)`.

Comment: Double check your first and last method arguments.  The first should probably be LongByReference, since it appears to want a pointer to a 64-bit value that the callee writes to.  The last should only be String[] if the callee *does not* write to the memory.  In either case, it's essential to know how the callee treats those arguments.

Comment: I tried it, but stays the same. I tried first to only convert the unused String Method-Parameters to Pointers. Later I tried also to convert the structure fields to pointers. I initialized the fields as Pointer.NULL and invoced the method also with Pointer.NULL for the unused Pointers.

Comment: What does your native example use as inputs for those other parameters?

Comment: Using Pointer for these char* fields ensures that JNA does not attempt to read them back when reading the structure from native memory after the function call.

Comment: Your native declaration and Java declaration return types need to match.  You've got `void` in native and `NativeLong` in Java.

Comment: OK I changed the return Type to 'void', the first argument to 'LongByReference' and the last to 'String[]'. I pass null for the string. I also made the valid boolean to a byte and set it to 1 for true. I wrote some lines of code in c++ and checked sizeof(TNativeFoo) and it is the same as input.size() both are 45. I the c++-demo the '#pragma pack(1)' is set. That corressbonds to 'ALIGN_NONE'.Or? But still there is the same mistake. Do I have to allocate the structures on the native heap or is this done by the Structure definition like this? Really thx, I'm glad for your help.

Comment: I tried to load the dll in c++ and it says on running the application: "Ungültiges Bild"(invalid build)-"C:\dlls\foodll.dll" is either not made for running on Windows or contains a mistake. ..." The dll did run with windows, and the dll should be correct. I will try it on a 32bit system.

Comment: OK there was a error in the dll files. Copied it again and the loading in c++ wasn't a problem anymore. But the Java code still throws an exception! But now I know the dll isn't wrong anymore. I will now try the call in c++. Perhaps this helps me get it right.

Comment: #pragma pack(1) corresponds to ALIGN_NONE, so you chose that correctly.  if the sizes for native and Java are the same, then it's unlikely that there are alignment issues.  JNA uses malloc-allocated memory for structures it allocates.

Comment: What is the Java exception you are seeing (or do you mean crash + dump)?

Comment: The Exception has changed after I had copied the dll from another place to resolve the dataerror in the dll-file. I recognized the problem, because I saw an exception in an c++-console-Application I wrote to get a clearer view of the dll usage. The new Java Exception is attached to the question.

Comment: That's a null pointer access, which likely means that at least one of your null parameters needs to be non-null.

Comment: I did a break on this project. But will continue to work on it soon. At the moment I'm thinking to build a facade in c++ and reduce the complexity of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using no alignment for your Structure?  That's the most likely cause of your crash.  Verify that the field offsets in Java (Structure.toString() will tell you) are the same as those in native code.

`PointerByReference` is intended to be passed to a function where the callee writes the value of a pointer into the address passed by the caller.  While your usage is technically correct, it actually obfuscates your actual intent.

If your structure contains a pointer of *any* kind, you should start with a type mapping of `Pointer`, and thereafter adjust the type mapping as needed.  `PointerByReference` is *never* appropriate as a structure field.

```
   public static class TNativeFoo extends com.sun.jna.Structure {

       public TNativeFoo (){ }
       public TNativeFoo(com.sun.jna.Pointer pointer, int offset) {
            super(pointer.share(offset));
            read();
        }
        public TNativeFoo(TNativeFoo struct) {
            super(struct.getPointer());
            read();
        }
        // NOTE: use Java conventions for field names, please
        private Pointer buffer;
        public Pointer data = new Memory(Pointer.SIZE);
        public NativeLong items;
        public Pointer irrelevantStringArray = new Memory(Pointer.SIZE);
        public NativeLong stringsCounts = new NativeLong(0);

        public double[] getData() { 
            Pointer p = data.getPointer(0);
            if (p == null) return null;
            return p.getDoubleArray(items.intValue());  
        }
        public void setData(double[] data) {
            Pointer p = this.data.getPointer(0);
            if (p == null) {
               p = buffer = new Memory(data.length * 8);    
               this.data.setPointer(0, buffer);
            }
            p.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
        }
    }

    NativeLong FooInterface(TNativeFoo input, TNativeFoo output);
}
```

Note that Double.SIZE is the size of a double in bits, not bytes, so you're allocating 8 times the size you actually need.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try it this way and come back!

Comment: Thanks for your help! ... I tried it this way, that didn't solve the Problem. Perhaps I'm closer now.

I also tried all Alignments, also no change. 

Perhaps there is a problem with a unused Handle-Parameter, which I excluded from the Method call. Is it OK to declare a Handle as Pointer in the function-interface definition. I invoke the function later with null. 

The TNativeFoo-Parameter is a void* Pointer in the c++ definition, but I believe its OK to declare and pass this in as TNativeFoo. 

Do you have any further suggestions?Or good reading.I didn't find so much explanations about JNA.

Comment: Really?  JNA documents quite extensively its usage in the project website, the JavaDoc, and the included examples and unit tests.  Under the section on support, it clearly indicates that when asking for help, you should provide both the native and (proposed) Java declarations for all relevant data structures and method signatures.  Without a side by side comparison, it's impossible to say whether you're not simply trivially leaving something out.  Are you using the proper calling convention?  Do your native/Java structure sizes match?

Comment: I read the JavaDoc. But there is for me something missing to get the details right (I'm more a managed-guy). The API-Doc is good to have, but the one sentence explanations there seem made for c++ guys. Perhaps it is not feasible to explain it for a none c++-Guy. Because it is a one time thing for me and I do not really think I could learn c++ in detail for it. Also this would be the right way to do it. I would need more examples.

Comment: The JNA documentation includes descriptions of proper structure and structure field mappings in both the github site pages and the JavaDoc overview page.  Feel free to make suggestions on the JNA project itself (either via the mailing list (http://groups.google.com/group/jna-users) or by opening a github issue (https://github.com/twall/jna/issues) on the project).

Comment: I didn't want to smaller the greate work of the jna-Team. Its complicated stuff they have to explain. And I'm totally new to this. Perhaps I will do an example out off my usage. After I get it right and understand the topic a little. I learn more out of examples and they must perhaps come out off the usage.

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestions:-

1. You should try using jnaerator for generating java code for the given c/c++ header.
      (Which will be a very good base to start).
2. Depending on the environment your native double/float size will be different from Java double/float. i.e native double might be equal to Java float. So you need to check this also.

So, you need to do bit of analysis of your own with different structure combinations to get what exactly native wants. If you don't pass exact then it will result in crash.

Kindly post your answer also.

Comment: #2 is extremely, extremely unlikely. I can't think of any modern CPU that doesn't follow the IEEE-754 spec (well IBM has their own format, but they support IEEE-754 as well).

Comment: Also thank you for your answer. I don't have the header file *g. Came to the project a few days ago and it seems the header file doesn't exist. I will post the answer if I get it working

Comment: If you don't have a header file, how do you know what the structure looks like in the first place?

Comment: The Author of the dll implemented a use-demo.

Comment: Presumably even the use demo has a definition for the structure, right?