# How to convers C++ Structure(compiled from Mathlab) in Java object using JNA

Tags: java, c++, structure, jna

I have this C++ Structure and Method, which it return inside of .dll/.so:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};

emxArray_real_T *emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols)
{
  emxArray_real_T *emx;
  ***
  return emx;
}
```

And I try to call it from Java via JNA. My goal is to receive this Struct "emxArray_real_T" in Java to obtain access to its fields.
I started from a very simple code and ended with this, but still have problems - I received the wrong data inside in "size", "data" etc.

```
public interface TestJna extends Library {
    TestJna INSTANCE = (TestJna)Native.load(Platform.isWindows() ? "some.dll" : "some.so", TestJna.class);

    @Structure.FieldOrder({"allocatedSize","canFreeData","data", "numDimensions", "size"})
    public static class ContentsJna extends Structure {

        public ContentsJna() {
        }

        public int allocatedSize;
        public boolean canFreeData;

        private Pointer bufferData;
        private Pointer bufferSize;
        public Pointer data = new Memory(Double.SIZE);
        public int numDimensions;
        public Pointer size = new Memory(Integer.SIZE);

        public double[] getData() {
            Pointer p = data.getPointer(0);
            if (p == null) return null;
            return p.getDoubleArray(0, allocatedSize);
        }

        public void setData(double[] data) {
            Pointer p = this.data.getPointer(0);
            if (p == null) {
                p = bufferData = new Memory(data.length * 8);
                this.data.setPointer(0, bufferData);
            }
            p.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
        }

        public int[] getSize() {
            Pointer p = data.getPointer(0);
            if (p == null) return null;
            return p.getIntArray(0, allocatedSize);
        }

        public void setSize(int[] size) {
            Pointer p = this.size.getPointer(0);
            if (p == null) {
                p = bufferSize = new Memory(size.length * 4);
                this.size.setPointer(0, bufferSize);
            }
            p.write(0, size, 0, size.length);
        }
    }
    ContentsJna emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols);
}
```

How can I fix it?
I followed this guide, but it doesn't helped me completely solve the problem:
[JNA native function call and a Structure with a Double**-Pointer/Array Memory-Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688120/jna-native-function-call-and-a-structure-with-a-double-pointer-array-memory-al)

UPD 16.02/21:
@Matthias Bläsing, thank you for this great solution - it helped me recognize my mistakes.
I have some wrong data output comparing to the C++ output.
Maybe I should provide the full C++ code:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};

emxArray_real_T *emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols)
{
  emxArray_real_T *emx;
  int numEl;
  emxInit_real_T(&emx, 2);
  emx->size[0] = rows;
  numEl = rows * cols;
  emx->size[1] = cols;
  emx->data = (double *)calloc((unsigned int)numEl, sizeof(double));
  emx->numDimensions = 2;
  emx->allocatedSize = numEl;
  return emx;
}

void emxInit_real_T(emxArray_real_T **pEmxArray, int numDimensions)
{
  emxArray_real_T *emxArray;
  int i;
  *pEmxArray = (emxArray_real_T *)malloc(sizeof(emxArray_real_T));
  emxArray = *pEmxArray;
  emxArray->data = (double *)NULL;
  emxArray->numDimensions = numDimensions;
  emxArray->size = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * numDimensions);
  emxArray->allocatedSize = 0;
  emxArray->canFreeData = true;
  for (i = 0; i < numDimensions; i++) {
    emxArray->size[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comparision outputs from C++ and Java for the call with arguments: `emxCreate_real_T(1024, 12)` here:

C++(correct):

```
=============
[0]:
data:  0.0
size:  1024
allocatedSize:  12288
numDimensions:  2
canFreeData:  True
=============
[1]:
data:  0.0
size:  12
allocatedSize:  12288
numDimensions:  2
canFreeData:  True
=============
[2]:
data:  0.0
size:  0
allocatedSize:  12288
numDimensions:  2
canFreeData:  True
=============
```

Java(incorrect):

```
=============
[0]:
data: 6.9475440396446E-310
size: -1672347344
allocatedSize: 32740
numDimensions: 12288
canFreeData: true
=============
[1]:
data: 6.94754379426234E-310
size: 32740
allocatedSize: 32740
numDimensions: 12288
canFreeData: true
=============
[2]:
data: 4.243997653E-314
size: 12288
allocatedSize: 32740
numDimensions: 12288
canFreeData: true
=============
```

I think the problem is in the allocation size differences like this:

```
emx->data = (double *)calloc((unsigned int)numEl, sizeof(double));
```

But have no idea how to solve it - using Byte and conversions to UnsignedInt doesn't help for me. :(

UPD: 20.02.21: @Matthias Bläsing Thanks again for your help.
How to write Getters and Setters to this new Structure, which contains Pointer("this pointer "*emxData"") to working Structure "emxArray_real_T"
C++ Structure code:

```
typedef struct {
  emxArray_real_T *emxData;
  double timeStamp;
} struct0T;
```

Java Structure Code:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"emxData","timeStamp"})
public class Struct0T extends Structure {

    public Pointer emxData;
    public double timeStamp;

    public emxArray_real_T getEmxData() {
        if (emxData == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("emxData is null");
        }
        // ???
        return ???;
    }

    public void setData(emxArray_real_T emxArray) {
        if (emxData == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("emxData is null");
        }
        final Pointer pointer = emxArray.getPointer(); // Or re-calculate Pointer by multiplying arrays size on Double/Integer sizes etc here for all fields?
        if(pointer == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("pointer is null");
        }
        this.emxData = pointer;
    }
}
```

Code inside Jna Library:

```
public interface TestJna extends Library {
***
    void calculation(emxArray_real_T input_str, emxArray_real_T output_str);
}
```

UPD 11.03.21: double[] <-> byte[] conversions(trying to solve Linux issue):

Changes in getData() setData:

```
public double[] getData() {
    final int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    if (data == null) {
        return new double[0];
    }
    return ByteDoubleConverterUtils.toDoubleArray(data.getByteArray(0, allocatedSize * times));
}

public void setData(double[] data) {
    final byte[] bytes = ByteDoubleConverterUtils.toByteArray(data);
    this.data.write(0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

Utility class:

```
public class ByteDoubleConverterUtils {

    public static byte[] toByteArray(double[] doubleArray){
        int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[doubleArray.length * times];
        for(int i=0;i<doubleArray.length;i++){
            final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, i * times, times);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            byteBuffer.putDouble(doubleArray[i]);
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    public static double[] toDoubleArray(byte[] byteArray){
        int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
        double[] doubles = new double[byteArray.length / times];
        for(int i=0;i<doubles.length;i++){
            final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, i * times, times);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            doubles[i] = byteBuffer.getDouble();
        }
        return doubles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, here I mean instead of this code:

`TestJna emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols);`

this one:

`ContentsJna emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols);`

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue is, that *@Structure.FieldOrder* is wrong. You need to match the native field order, so that the runtime can associate the right java variable with the right memory location. With your declaration the first member is *allocatedSize* (java site), but in the native code, it is the pointer to *data*.

```java
@Structure.FieldOrder({"data", "size", "allocatedSize", "numDimensions", "canFreeData"})
public static class emxArray_real_T extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference extends emxArray_real_T implements Structure.ByReference {
        public ByReference() {
        }

        public ByReference(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
        }
    }

    public Pointer data;
    public Pointer size;
    public int allocatedSize = 1;
    public int numDimensions = 1;
    public boolean canFreeData = false;

    public emxArray_real_T() {
    }

    public emxArray_real_T(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
    }

    public double[] getData() {
    if (data == null) {
        return new double[0];
    }
    return data.getDoubleArray(0, allocatedSize);
    }

    public void setData(double[] data) {
    if (data.length != allocatedSize) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data must have a length of " + allocatedSize + " but was " + data.length);
    }
    this.data.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
    }

    public int[] getSize() {
    if (size == null) {
        return new int[0];
    }
    return size.getIntArray(0, numDimensions);
    }

    public void setSize(int[] size) {
    if (size.length != numDimensions) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size must have a length of " + numDimensions + " but was " + size.length);
    }
    this.size.write(0, size, 0, size.length);
    }
}
```

When you use this, please check if boolean_T is 32bit. If it is 1byte, map to byte.

For the Structure that holds a reference to the `emxArray_real_T` you need a Structure, that implements the marker interface `com.sun.jna.Structure.ByReference`. Structures with that marker interface are passed by reference and when embedded into other structures, a pointer to the structures is embedded into the parent structure and not the child itself.

```java
@Structure.FieldOrder({"emxData","timeStamp"})
public class Struct0T extends Structure {

    public emxArray_real_T.ByReference emxData;
    public double timeStamp;
}
```

To convert from Structure to Structure.ByReference you can run (if this comes from native):

```java
    emxArray_real_T.ByReference t1ByReference = Structure.newInstance(emxArray_real_T.ByReference.class, input.getPointer());
    t1ByReference.read();
```

If the structure was created on the java side and the data is backed by a Memory object, it is advised to use a copy constructor, so that the reference is kept intact.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added the C++ full code in my initial post and also the output difference between C++ and Java. I can't realize how to deal with those differences in outputs.:( Thank you again for your help

Comment: You are right - the binding for the arrays was not correct, please check the updated version.

Comment: Thanks - you solved my problem with this data structure and data binding! Without your help - I will not move forward in this task. Actually, you saved my life in my project - thank you again!

If someone else will copy-paste use your solution - two small corrections:
In method "getSize()" instead of "data" we should use "size" like this: "return size.getIntArray(0, numDimensions);" and in the "@Structure.FieldOrder" we should change "boolean_T" on "canFreeData"

Comment: Thanks for the check and reply with the correction. I adjusted the sample code according to you reply and rereading you are of course right.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Now I stuck in the next step - I have a Structure, that contains the Pointer on our previous Structure and method inside .dll/.so, which converts data in our emxArray_real_T and returns this emxArray_real_T as output result with corrected data. How to write Getters/Setters for Pointer on "emxArray_real_T" inside our new  Structure "struct0T"? 

I put the code example at the end of my question.

Comment: Updated the answer with sample implementation and explanation.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Your solution is working for me except for one thing - I need to create an Instance of Struct0T for this method "void calculation(emxArray_real_T input_str, emxArray_real_T output_str);". So I have an Instance of emxArray_real_T(obtained from .dll) - so how to write Constructor(or Setter) for the code like this: "new Struct0T(exmArrayRealTInst.ByRefference, timestamp)" (.i.e how to obtain this field "emxArray_real_T.ByRefference" inside Java)? Or this is impossible due to  "a pointer to the structures is embedded into the parent structure and not the child itself.?"

Comment: If read your question as "How do I convert a Structure to Structure.ByReference"? If so, have a look at the `Structure.newInstance` and `Structure.getPointer`. I'll update the example with the code suited for that.

Comment: Thank you again - it's working! I just added in both Constructors with "Pointer p" this code: "read();" after "super(p);" and now I have all data inside child Structure! Thanks again!

Comment: I faced with a small issue - in Windows the original code getData()/setData() works perfect with .dll. But in Linux, the Python equivalent works with .so  same as Windows Java code, but Java code sends/receives from the .so wrong doubles. In UPD 11.03.21 I show how I played with LITTLE_ENDIAN/BIG_ENDIAN(used all 4 combinations in 2 utility methods) without effect. Any idea how to change bytes in ByteArray for Linux to send/get correct doubles from the Pointer?

Comment: This becomes excessive. Provide minimal code, that reproduces your problem and can be called without additional work, else this is pure speculation, but if the code looks to complicated to be correct. A quick google showed, that real_T is not always double, it could be float, so if your definitions are wrong, you are reading floats as doubles, which breaks hard.