# JNA: truncated double's from Pointers in Linux(in Windows all is OK)

Tags: java, c++, pointers, double, jna

I use this solution to call the JNA method from .dll/.so library:
[Creating C++ Structures via JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210287/how-to-convers-c-structurecompiled-from-mathlab-in-java-object-using-jna)

And in Windows, this code works perfect, but in Linux, I receive truncated double values, so from the Pointer data
in Windows, I receive this value:

```
40.7
```

from these bytes in Pointer:

```
[64, 68, 89, -103, -103, -103, -103, -102]
```

But in Linux I have this instead:

```
40.0
[64, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

.so/.dll was compiled from the same source and from the Python(by using "ctypes") I obtain correct values in Linux from the same .so

I already tried to write/read byte[] to/from Pointer - nothing happened - in Windows, all OK, but in the Linux, doubles are truncated.

This is C++ Structure and Method, which it returns inside of .dll/.so:

```
struct emxArray_real_T
{
  double *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  boolean_T canFreeData;
};

emxArray_real_T *emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols)
{
  emxArray_real_T *emx;
  ***
  return emx;
}
```

And this code in Java:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"data", "size", "allocatedSize", "numDimensions", "canFreeData"})
public class emxArray_real_T extends Structure {

    public Pointer data;
    public Pointer size;
    public int allocatedSize = 1;
    public int numDimensions = 1;
    public boolean canFreeData = false;

    ***

    public double[] getData() {
        if (data == null) {
            return new double[0];
        }
        return data.getDoubleArray(0, allocatedSize);
    }

    public void setData(double[] data) {
        if (data.length != allocatedSize) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data must have a length of " + allocatedSize + " but was "
                    + data.length);
        }
        this.data.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
    }
    ***
}
```

UPD: Obtaining bytes from `Pointer data`:

```
public byte[] getDataByte() {
    final int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    if (data == null) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
    return data.getByteArray(0, allocatedSize * times);
}
```

UPD2: I receive this error when I try to write the double like this `-0.0000847` in the `Pointer data` in Linux(so it seems in Linux .so somehow use C type 'int' to the double representation):

`Expected a value representable in the C type 'int'.  Found inf instead. Error in ballshaftpasses (line 61)`

UPD3: double[] <-> byte[] conversions(trying to solve Linux issue):

Changes in getData() setData:

```
public double[] getData() {
    final int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    if (data == null) {
        return new double[0];
    }
    return ByteDoubleConverterUtils.toDoubleArray(data.getByteArray(0, allocatedSize * times));
}

public void setData(double[] data) {
    final byte[] bytes = ByteDoubleConverterUtils.toByteArray(data);
    this.data.write(0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

Utility class:

```
public class ByteDoubleConverterUtils {

    public static byte[] toByteArray(double[] doubleArray){
        int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[doubleArray.length * times];
        for(int i=0;i<doubleArray.length;i++){
            final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, i * times, times);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            byteBuffer.putDouble(doubleArray[i]);
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    public static double[] toDoubleArray(byte[] byteArray){
        int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
        double[] doubles = new double[byteArray.length / times];
        for(int i=0;i<doubles.length;i++){
            final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, i * times, times);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            doubles[i] = byteBuffer.getDouble();
        }
        return doubles;
    }
}
```

UPD4:
C++ Function Example
This is C++ function example to reproduce problems in Linux:

```
void emx_copy(const emxArray_real_T *in, emxArray_real_T *res)
{
    int i0;
    int loop_ub;
    i0 = res->size[0] * res->size[1];
    res->size[0] = in->size[0];
    res->size[1] = in->size[1];
    emxEnsureCapacity_real_T(res, i0);
    loop_ub = in->size[0] * in->size[1];
    for (i0 = 0; i0 < loop_ub; i0++) {
        res->data[i0] = in->data[i0] * in->data[i0];
    }
}
```

Java JNA Interface:

```
public interface EmxJna extends Library {
    FcnOpjJna INSTANCE = (EmxJna)Native.load(Native.load(Platform.isWindows() ? "emx.dll" : "emx.so", EmxJna.class);
    emxArray_real_T emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols);
    void emx_copy(emxArray_real_T in, emxArray_real_T res);
}
```

Java test Method to call lib and set values `40.7` and `-0.0000847` in `Pointer data`:

```
private void emxTest() {
    final emxArray_real_T input = FcnOpjJna.INSTANCE.emxCreate_real_T(128, 32);
    final double[] inputData = input.getData();
    inputData[0] = 40.7d;
    inputData[1] = -0.0000847d;
    input.setData(inputData);
    final emxArray_real_T output = FcnOpjJna.INSTANCE.emxCreate_real_T(128, 32);
    FcnOpjJna.INSTANCE.emx_copy(input, output);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "bytes in Pointer".  Please show the code you are using to produce those different values.  How is the `size` field supposed to be used?  What is the size of the arrays?  How is the data being set in the first place to know that one is correct and the other is not?  What does the API say about the allocation of memory for the result at the pointed-to value and who is responsible for freeing it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - first I call from JNA this method `*emxCreate_real_T(int rows, int cols)`, which return a Structure `emxArray_real_T`. Pointer `data` points to the memory, which contains doubles(number of doubles is `allocatedSize`), the same situation happened with Pointer `size` and `numDimensions`(number of elements in `size`).

Comment: Then I can set some new values in `Pointer data`(without changing its size) and call other methods from dll/so, which process this data and can change data in this Pointer(size and address of this Pointer are the same). In windows all OK, but in Linux, I obtain truncated doubles(and .so receive from me truncated doubles too). So I'm interested - can I run my JVM with some specific flags or do something else to sends to the .so Method and receive from .so Method normal doubles(instead truncated).

Comment: `this.data.write(0, data, 0, data.length);` looks suspicious. `data.length` is just the length of the array.  But you want to write a number of bytes so you need `data.length * times` there.  You may just be only writing the first two bytes.

Comment: Thanks, but data.write in this case is a special method to writing double[], so it works correctly. One thing that I found - I receive this error when I try to write the double like this `-0.0000847` in the `Pointer data` in Linux(so it seems in Linux .so somehow use C type 'int' to the double representation):
`Expected a value representable in the C type 'int'.  Found inf instead.
Error in ballshaftpasses (line 61)`.
Any idea how to convert doubles to C type 'int'?

Comment: Sorry, was going off memory. You're correct `length` there is the array length.  As far as the error with `int` that is strange and must be something associated with the API.  `int` is normally a 4 byte number.  `double` is normally an 8 byte number.  You need to consult the API to see what format it expects a `double` in.

Comment: OK, I [found the api](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html) which would be good to include with your question.  I can't see anything wrong with your mapping but I still do not understand what you mean by "I already tried to write/read byte[] to/from Pointer" and "I try to write the double like this -0.0000847".  You have not shown the code you are actually using to write the data, which may be where the problem is.  You're only showing the structures, not how you are using them.  Please post your complete code.

Comment: I mean by "I already tried to write/read byte[] to/from Pointer" the code in UPD3. I try to play with `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN` and `ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN` with no success. The code with `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN` gives me correct outputs in Windows, but the same incorrect values in Linux as with `getDouble()` approach. About "I try to write the double like this -0.0000847" - if Library set those negative values I see -Infinity in Linux Java App, but if I set this negative values to double[], use `setData(double[] data) {*}` and call Lib in Linux I receive above error about C type 'int'.

Comment: So I try to figure out which byte sequence instead of `[64, 68, 89, -103, -103, -103, -103, -102]` I should use in Linux in ByteDoubleConverterUtils to be able to send/receive to/from .so library correct doubles in the `byte[]` representation. And can't understand why in Windows all OK, but in Linux I obtained truncated doubles from positive doubles like `40.7` and -Infinity instead of negative doubles like this: `-0.0000847`.

Comment: C++ function inside of .so/.dll works in this way - I call it with 2 arguments `callFunc(emxArray_real_T input, emxArray_real_T output)` and this function takes values from `input` do some calculations inside and put result values in the `output`. And only in Linux if I put in the `data` inside `input` values like  `40.7` function see it as `40.0` if I put values like ` -0.0000847` I obtain error `Expected a value representable in the C type 'int'.  Found inf instead. ***`. And vise-versa - if function return me in output `40.7` I see `40.0` and if it return `-0.0000847` I see `-Infinity`.

Comment: Please tell me which callFunc() you are using from the API.  Please tell me which function you are using to set the values in the input array.  Please update your original question with this code.   Your problem is probably in how you are setting the values in the `input` of your function but if you do not show us your code we can't guess.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I added code examples in UPD4:

Comment: It's a specific JDK on Ubuntu issue. When I try to run my code in Docker Image `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` all is OK. But locally with java:8.0.212-zulu I have this issue. So somehow Azul Zulu Builds for Java8 and Java11, run on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 convert doubles to integers in this me code. Maybe I use wrong default JVM flags etc

Comment: I still think there's something up with number of bytes read/written somewhere.  In UPD (1), why do you calculate `times` in `return data.getByteArray(0, allocatedSize * times);` ?   Is it possible it's just the first two bytes (which match) that are supposed to be returned, and the rest of the values are just random memory/garbage which may be platform dependent?